# How can I assign a Promise<string> to a String type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-storage

I'm super new to the world of Javascript and React.
I'm currently building an app using the Ionic framework. It's using an existing firebase Project.

Im trying to fetch avatar images from firebase storage, using this function in my react component:

```
  async function getAvatarRef(avatarId: string): Promise<String> {
    const avatarUrl = await avatarsRef.child(avatarId).getDownloadURL();
    return avatarUrl.toString();
  }
```

then I'm calling that function to get the download URL using the UserID that I'm grabbing from Firebase Auth here:

```
<IonImg src={getAvatarRef(child.avatarId)} />
```

My issue though is that the function is returning a `Promise<string>` but the `src` property from `IonImage` is wanting just a simple `String` type

This is the error I'm getting: `Type 'Promise<string>' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

I've looked all over but can't seem to find a solution.

Anyone here have any ideas?

Comment: All async functions always return a promise that resolves asynchronously.  You won't be able to make it synchronous - the final promise must be awaited or dealt with somehow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is an *effect*. You are fetching data from a server and rendering that in your component.

If you are using functional components, you want to have a look at the `useState` and `useEffect` hooks. For class components, you need to use state and a lifecycle method on your component.

Essentially, your `src` attribute should be a state item (something that can change during the lifetime of your component that will require react to update the DOM) that you may initialize as an empty string or a local placeholder image.

Then your effect code would update the value of your state and react will handle telling the DOM what changed.

EDIT: I should add that there is nothing wrong with using an async function inside a `useEffect` hook. Note that the callback function `useEffect` expects *cannot* be asynchronous. But there is nothing stopping you from putting an async function inside the callback and calling it there. Or using an async IIFE. Both are common patterns in React...

Answer (score 1):

React hooks would be applicable in situations like this. Here's an example using your code snippets

```
function YourComp() {
      const [avatarUrl, setAvatarUrl] = useState<string>('');

      // run effect once 
     useEffect(() => {
        getUrl();
      }, []);
         
      async function getAvatarRef(avatarId: string): Promise<String> {
        const avatarUrl = await avatarsRef.child(avatarId).getDownloadURL();
        return avatarUrl.toString();
      }

     // Resolve Promise<string> to string
      const getUrl = (): void => getAvatarRef(
       child.avatarId
      ).then((res) =>
        setAvatarUrl(res.avatarUrl)
      );


     
      return <IonImg src={avatarUrl} />
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead, call the `promise` first then set the `src` using the result:

```
getAvatarRef(child.avatarId).then(src => someImg.src = src);
```